# Spring Security + Angular JS + Spring MVC Rest

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I am trying to build a web application with the following frameworks:

- Angular JS on the front end
- REST Web Services in the backend using Spring MVC

I want to use Spring Security to authenticate all the requests going from Angular JS to Spring REST Web services. I also need to manage the session timeout/remember password etc. (All of the typical functionalities of a login functionality in a web app)

I have gone over hundreds of articles trying to find out how to do this but none of them is exactly serving the purpose I am asking for.

Any help on this (inline answer or external links) with detailed steps is highly appreciated.

**(Note: I don't want to use Spring boot. Many tutorials including the one provided by Spring is using Spring boot.)**

Comment: If this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33751988/1679484

Comment: @AmitParashar this article doesnt talk about Spring security at all.

Comment: Spring security layer does not need  special configuration for angular js generated requests.Try to set up a simple web project with spring security andspring MVC first, and then incorporate changes to introduce AngularJS in your project.

Comment: @AmitParashar I cant find a good example to do that as well!! As I am using REST webservices using MVC.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Comment: @AmitParashar This doesnt serve the purpose as it deals with web applications. I am looking at securing REST services that use Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the way to do this. Clearly explained, step by step process to secure a Spring MVC based REST APIs using Spring Security

https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/stateless-spring-security-on-rest-api/